# Why CryptImportKey failed?

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, aes, cryptoapi

I'm trying to use the Windows CryptoAPI functions for AES encryption.

I want to give my own key to the CryptEncrypt function but my CryptImportKey function failes

here is my code:

```
    HCRYPTPROV hProv  = NULL;
    HCRYPTKEY hKey    = NULL;
    DWORD dwBlobLen;
    PBYTE pbKeyBlob = NULL;
    pbKeyBlob = (PBYTE)"1a1dc91c907325c6";

    if(!CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, NULL,NULL, PROV_RSA_AES,CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
    {
        printf(" Error in AcquireContext 0x%08x \n",GetLastError());
    }    
    if (!CryptImportKey(hProv,pbKeyBlob,sizeof(pbKeyBlob),0,CRYPT_EXPORTABLE,&hKey ))
    {
        printf("Error 0x%08x in importing the Des key \n",GetLastError());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use AES your key should be at least 16 bytes long, you have 8 byte long key. AES uses 128, 192 or 256 bits long keys.